# PL-SQL: returning error - inserting elements into (user input) index with shifting all the elements to element[i+1]

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
TYPE arr is VARRAY(10) of VARCHAR(32);
ar arr := arr('1', '1', '1');
idx INTEGER(100);
tmp INTEGER(100);
val VARCHAR(32);

PROCEDURE APPENDARR (arr IN OUT arr, idx IN, val IN) IS

BEGIN
    if(idx > arr.LIMIT) then
    tmp := (idx - arr.LIMIT);
    arr.extend(tmp);

    FOR i in REVERSE idx..arr.LAST LOOP
    arr(i) := arr(i - 1);
    if(arr(i) = arr(idx)) THEN
    arr(i) := val;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    ELSE
    arr.extend();
    arr(idx) := val;
    END IF;


END;
```

error code:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 48:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

out  
long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary
national character nchar

anyone who can help me with my error? sorry english is not my native language but i try my best :)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is part of a package, as otherwise you would need the `create or replace` syntax. For demo purposes, I put it in an anonymous block just to test compilation.

Two issues:

1. `integer` doesn't take a precision, it's just `integer`.
2. The `idx` and `val` parameters are missing datatypes.

The following compiles (I haven't checked what it does or whether there is any better implementation):

```
declare
    type arr is varray(10) of varchar(32);
    ar  arr := arr('1', '1', '1');
    idx integer;
    tmp integer;
    val varchar(32);

    procedure appendarr
        ( arr in out arr
        , idx in integer
        , val in varchar2 )
    is
    begin
        if idx > arr.limit then
            tmp := idx - arr.limit;
            arr.extend(tmp);
        
            for i in reverse idx .. arr.last loop
                arr(i) := arr(i - 1);

                if arr(i) = arr(idx) then
                    arr(i) := val;
                end if;
            end loop;
        else
            arr.extend();
            arr(idx) := val;
        end if;
    
    end;
begin
    null;
end;
```

PL/SQL `if` conditions are terminated by the `then` keyword so they don't need brackets as in other languages, so I removed them.

Also, you have variables `idx`, `tmp` and `val` declared at the top which are not used anywhere, and which also have the same names as local variables within the procedure, which could be confusing. If there isn't some more code you haven't shown that uses them, maybe you can get rid of them.

**Edit:** As requested, here is what it would look like as a standalone procedure:

```
create or replace type arr as varray(10) of varchar(32)
/
```

```
create or replace procedure appendarr
    ( arr in out arr
    , idx in integer
    , val in varchar2 )
as
    tmp integer;
begin
    if idx > arr.limit then
        tmp := idx - arr.limit;
        arr.extend(tmp);

        for i in reverse idx .. arr.last loop
            arr(i) := arr(i - 1);
            if arr(i) = arr(idx) then
                arr(i) := val;
            end if;
        end loop;
    else
        arr.extend();
        arr(idx) := val;
    end if;
    
end appendarr;
/
```

(The `/` character is required by some development tools to separate blocks, but is not part of the PL/SQL language itself.)

It seems the aim is to insert value `val` into element `idx` of array `arr`, shifting existing values up one place. However, it doesn't quite work:

```
declare
    ar  arr := arr('First', 'Second');
begin
    appendarr
    ( arr => ar
    , idx => 2
    , val => 'New value' );

    for i in ar.first..ar.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i||' '||ar(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

```
1 First
2 New value
3
```

Fixed version:

```
create or replace type varchar2_tt as table of varchar2(50)
/
```

```
create or replace procedure varchar2_tt_append
    ( arr in out varchar2_tt
    , pos in pls_integer default null
    , val in varchar2 )
as
    idx pls_integer := nvl(pos,arr.last +1);
begin
    if idx > arr.last then
        arr.extend(idx - arr.last);
    else
        arr.extend();

        for i in reverse greatest(idx,2)..arr.last loop
            arr(i) := arr(i - 1);
        end loop;
    end if;

    arr(idx) := val;
    
end varchar2_tt_append;
/
```

Test:

```
declare
    ar  varchar2_tt := varchar2_tt('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth');
begin
    varchar2_tt_append
    ( arr => ar
    , pos => 1
    , val => 'New value' );

    for i in ar.first..ar.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i||' '||ar(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

```
1 New value
2 First
3 Second
4 Third
5 Fourth
```

Comment: thank you for your fast response and thank you for the tips and example (/corrected) syntax. i have a question, why is it a problem for PL-SQL to compile this procedure without this syntax in it: "begin
    null;
end;"

Comment: Because it isn't a standalone procedure (`create or replace procedure appendarr`), and along with `type arr` it appears to be part of a larger block. Therefore I placed it in the `declare` section of a dummy block just to test compiling it. If you want to call it, replace `null;` with a call to the procedure.

Comment: so basically a procedure cant be compiled without an extra anonymous block? thank you, didnt know that!

Comment: That’s not what I said. If your intention was to create a reusable, standalone procedure, then you’d need to use `create or replace procedure appendarr`, and also decide how you wanted to declare the type `arr`.

Comment: thank you for your fast response, could you show me an example what you mean with declaring the type arr?

Comment: Sure. First though, can you clarify whether the code you posted is part of a larger unit, such as a package? Because as posted, it would give a different error.

Comment: it is homework just to write procedure who adds elements etc.. basically no package

Comment: Does your assignment specifically require a `varray`? In general varrays are less useful than nested-table collections and associative arrays in PL/SQL code (they are more useful for database table columns), as they just give you reduced functionality plus a LIMIT you don't need.